# Meteor Session.get and if()

Tags: mongodb, if-statement, meteor

I'm testing the Meteor example leaderboard and have a problem with getting data from Mongo.

I want a button to subtract the score, but only if score > 0. My database and code:

**Database:**

```
Players.insert({
            name: "Mike",
            totalscore: [20, 25]
        });
```

**Code:**

```
Template.vote.events({
'click input.dec': function () {
    var temp = Players.find(Session.get("selected_player", totalscore[1]));
    if (temp > 0) {
        Players.update(Session.get("selected_book"), {$inc: {totalscore: -1}});
        }
    }
});
```

**JavaScript Console:**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: totalscore is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error comes because of you have used `totalscore[1]` in  `Players.find()`.

You are updating `totalscore` as if it is an integer, and actually it is stored as an array. which is completely irrelevant for score attribute. Please use the number instead of array for `totalscore` and update the click event like this:

```
var temp = Players.findOne(Session.get("selected_player"));
if (temp && parseInt(temp.totalscore, 10) > 0) {
    Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {totalscore: -1}});
}
```

Comment: Hello, it works, but I've two questions:
1. What means the number 10 in your code?
2. If I have buttons with +10 and -10, then I can give 7 points (with +1 button) and with button -10 the result is -3 (that is under 0)

Comment: 1. The number 10 in `parseInt()` is the value for radix. see the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
2. You must specify the condition for that, if the `totalscore` is 0 then do not perform the `update` query.